# Polyval(p,x) to evaluate polynomials

Tags: python, numpy

I don't know much about Python and I'm trying to use it to do some simple polynomial interpolation, but there's something I'm not understanding about one of the built-in functions.

I'm trying to use `polyval(p,x)` to evaluate a polynomial p at x.

I made an example polynomial p(x) = 1 + 2x + x^3, I created an array `p = [1,2,0,1]` to define it and I want to know the values at x = 0,1,2 so I created another array `x = [0,1,2]`.

Doing `polyval(p,x)` gave me an output of `[1, 4, 17]`. `p(0)` and `p(1)` are correct, but `p(2)` should be 13, not 17. Why is it giving me 17?

Comment: ```polyval``` is a numpy function, not a Python built-in - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are entering the coefficients in reverse order.

[According to the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html), the equation

```
p(x) = 1*x^3 + 0*x^2 + 2*x + 1
```

has coefficients

```
p = [1, 0, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your p array is in the wrong order. You should start with the coefficient of the highest exponent.
Try with p=[1,0,2,1].